# push option missing in source control xcode

Tags: xcode, git, push, xcode4.5

I have clone a xcode project from BigBucket using terminal window. Then I made changes in one of the file. When I went to commit the changes I got an option as commit within source control. After successful commit when I want to push that changes to remote server I did not find any option to Push changes. Push option is missing within source control.

In my organizer window-> Repositories I checked whether remote is added or not, but that is absolutely fine.

What I am missing in my setup? There must be something that I missed out.

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: Sometimes when you make a commit the push option is enabled maybe check that

Answer (score 0):

After a commit, you first have to pull possible changes from the server. Only then you can push your changes up. In other words, as long as you did no pull after a commit, push is not available.

Comment: Even I do not see pull option :( Screen shot is attached to question